# caret package: Is it possible to implement my own bootstrapping method?

Tags: r

I am using [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf) package for R to select variables for my model. When using **rfe** command, one should pass rfeControl object, which has a **method** parameter. Options for this parameter are boot, cv, LOOCV and LGOCV. Since I am dealing with time series data I need to use special bootstrapping/cross-validation techniques as normal ones do not apply for time series data (otherwise distributions get corrupted etc.).

My question is how would I plug-in my own implementation of bootstrapping but still use caret **rfe** method, which has every other thing I need.

Comment: generally speaking, you can peruse the source code to see how it fits in with the rest of the code and make the modifications necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way. If you study the code for `rfe.default()` you will note that in cases where `method = "boot"` the `createResample()` function is used. This is the function that generates the bootstrap samples. Similar functions are used for the other CV methods.

There is a hard way; overtake the `create*()` function that is most appropriate; say you want to do a block bootstrap or ME bootstrap, take over the `createResample()` function and use `method = "boot"`, or if you want a special form of CV, use `method = "cv"` and take over `createFolds()`.

You will need to write your own `create*()` function and replace the one in the caret NAMESPACE with your version. Not easy but eminently doable. Say you write your own `createResample()` function; first you need to note that this function creates *n* = `times` bootstrap samples returning this in a matrix with `times` columns and as many rows as your have samples. You need to write a custom `createResample()` function that returns the same object but which performs the time series bootstrapping you want to employ.

Once you have written that function you then need to get it into the caret namespace so that it is used by functions in the caret package. For this you use `assignInNamespace()`. Say your new bootstrapping function is called `createMyResample()` and it is your workspace, to insert this into the caret namespace do:

```
assignInNamespace("createResample", createMyResample, ns = "caret")
```

Sorry I can't be more specific but you don't say *how* you want the bootstrap/CV to be performed nor what R code you want to use to do the resampling. If you provide further details on how you would do the resampling I will take another look and see if I can help you write your `create*()` function.

Failing all of this, contact Max Kuhn, the author and maintainer of caret; he may be able to advice further or at least you can suggest this feature as a wish-list for a future version.

Comment: @Max has been seen hereabouts, maybe this will raise him to comment?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your advice is spot on. There is another difficulty I am dealing with, namely I looked at createResample function and the output are _indices_ of the examples. Since the meboot package that I will be using outputs _bootstrapped timeseries_ and not _indices_, that is additional difficulty. Will try to see if caret's rfe can be twisted to account for that.

BTW: the assignInNamespace should take only the name of function as the first parameter, so "createResample" instead of "createResample()".

Comment: @GregaKešpret Thanks for spotting the typo. Will fix that. It will probably be easier to hack **meboot** to return indices than to hack **caret** to accept time series - the latter is not designed that way so as to be as modular as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately meboot does not just do basic bootstrapping, it actually changes elements within each ensemble so as to randomize and preserve maximum entropy at the same time. So I guess I won't be able to use __caret__ after all.

Comment: Ah, OK. Sorry didn't realise that was what ME boot did.